# How to change default saltenv?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to change the default saltenv value on my salt master.

I need that all minions get the `production` environment from my salt master. Il removed the `base` environment, and made the following configurations :

```
file_roots:
  production:
    - /srv/salt/production/states
    - /srv/salt/production/formulas
pillar_roots:
  production:
    - /srv/salt/production/pillar
```

And :

```
state_top_saltenv: production
default_top: production
top_file_merging_strategy: same
```

But, when I run :

`salt  'myminion'  state.highstate` I get : 
`No Top file or master_tops data matches found. Please see master log for details.`

Running `state.apply`, it works.

Why is this ? How to get state.apply and state.highstate behave accordingly ?

I came with those settings by trying to understand the documentation, but I know it's not configured the way I want it :

- the production environment should be the only one to be selected on minion scheduled run
- environments should be isolated, no merging of data from different environments
- ability to configure individual minions to run a different saltenv
- ability to run a specific saltenv from the master (with `saltenv=devel` for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to move from `base` saltenv to `production` one is the following:

- in states top.sls, change all `base:` occurence
- in pillars top.sls, do the same
- in minion configuration specify its env with `saltenv: production`

Last step may be unneeded if you use `default_top: production`.

I think that's all, I have some minimal code with kitchen tests to validate it that I can share if you need it.

**update**: `default_top: production` is sufficient for highstates to run correctly, but is not enough if you want to run specific states *(with `salt <minion> state.sls foo`)* => you will need to specify `saltenv` argument in the command-line or add it to your minion config

Comment: Thank you for your contrinbution. I've worked it out the same way as you did.
I'm not realy positive about it but beware with `top_file_merging_strategy` ... Salt default behaviour is to merge the environments, which IMHO is very dangerous when you use environment as described ...

Comment: In fact. We plan to have only environment per machine (using minion config to set it) so that the merge_strategy shouldn't affect us.